Possible typescript issue when having a prop called "valueOf"?
This gives an error as expected:
type Paulo = {
  prop: string,
  otherValueOf: string,
}

type Treta = Record<keyof Paulo, () => Object>

const ugulha : Treta = { //Error: Property 'otherValueOf' is missing
  prop: () => 1,
}

But this is just fine:
type Paulo = {
  prop: string,
  valueOf: string,
}

type Treta = Record<keyof Paulo, () => Object>

const ugulha : Treta = {
  prop: () => 1,
}

Probably no one would ever have a prop called valueOf but maybe there are some mechanics that I am missing

Guessing it's a reserved keyword thing? I'm curious to know tho

Every javascript object1 automatically inherits a valueOf property: Object.prototype.valueOf(). So ugulha does in fact have a valueOf property, and that value is a function that returns an Object, which matches your type definition.
Note for example that the following code executes without error:


const ugulha = {
  prop: () => 1,
}
console.log(ugulha.valueOf())



1) except objects with a null prototype
